# Let a java function wait for a button to be clicked until it returns

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, user-interface, event-handling

I'm trying to implement a function **showTexfieldSettingsDialouge(Map fields)** in a little 'code generator'-application, taking a Hashmap full of Strings as input, showing a swing window with iteratively created panels and text-fields, for every key mentioned in the Hashmap, and returning this Hashmap filled with the inputs by the user, after clicking a button.

The Problem: To wait for the button to be clicked, I have to create an ActionListener, which runs in a new (the Swing-)Thread. 
**How can I let the function wait for the ActionListener to be fired, to go on, write the input an then return?**

For better help I may post the code I wrote until now:

```
public class GUIMacroHandler {

    //diverse other functions

    public HashMap<String, String> showTexfieldSettingsDialouge(Map<String, String> fields){

    JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame("Please fill every Textfield with the correct Data");
    Map<String, JLabel> labels = new HashMap<String, JLabel>();
    Map<String, JTextField> textfields = new HashMap<String, JTextField>();
    JPanel optionpanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(fields.size(), 2, 10, 10));
    JSplitPane splitPane = new JSplitPane();
    JButton btnSubmit = new JButton("Submit");


    splitPane.setOrientation(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT);
    mainFrame.getContentPane().add(splitPane, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    splitPane.setTopComponent(optionpanel);
    splitPane.setBottomComponent(btnSubmit);

    for (Entry<String, String> entry : fields.entrySet()) {
        labels.put(entry.getKey(),new JLabel(entry.getKey() + ":"));
        textfields.put(entry.getKey(),new JTextField(entry.getValue());
        optionpanel.add(labels.get(entry.getKey()));
        optionpanel.add(textfields.get(entry.getKey()));
    }



    btnSubmit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            //Can't do stuff here because the function needs to return after the button is clicked and not before
        }
    });   

    mainFrame.pack();
    mainFrame.setVisible(true);

    //TODO:

    //Wait for button to be clicked somehow

    //Fill the given values with the input of the text fields

    return fields;
    }
}
```

The function is cast more than once in the code and is thought to easily change any given String/String HashMap by user wanted values.
f.e. like so:

```
GUIMacroHandler guiMacroHandler = new GUIMacroHandler();
combatsettings = guiMacroHandler.showTexfieldSettingsDialouge(combatsettings);
```

I've googled a whole time an didn't found a solution for my problem, I would be really happy for help, thanks in advance! :D

**Edit:**
Just post the stuff in the Action performed statement would only be a possible solution if I would use this function only once in the code, but not here because the function **is forced to wait for the button to be clicked to return** In the actual code the gui window would get created with the inputs of the Hashmap an then return the given Hashmap and the code would go on with no user input, the window would still exist, waiting for the button to be clicked to eventually expire, but no use for user changed data and code would go on with the defaults, because it doesn't waits for the users input.

Comment: Why not do the stuff in the action listener?

Comment: What Murat says. Just perform your operation in the listener's `actionPerformed` method, as per design.

Comment: Would be a possible solution if I would use this function only once in the code, but how to get the filled map in the return statement if  casted like shown? - In the actual code the gui window would get created with the inputs of the Hashmap an then return the given Hashmap and the code would go on with no user input, the window would still exist, waiting for the button to be clicked to eventually expire, but no use for user changed data and code would go on with the defaults, because it doesn't waits for the users input.

Comment: The only way for the code to "wait" is to block the thread on the listener execution, which would block the window rendering until your listener resolved, which would make your program be unresponsive. Is there any reason for you not to update your values at the listener, instead of relying on the return value of your method? You could pass your `guiMacroHandler` as a parameter and update the values at the listener.

Comment: Isn't the window-rendering running in a new swing thread? - So it should be no problem to let the thread sleep and wait for action-performed to fire something that the thread wakes up, or am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like that if you're sure that you're calling this method from some thread != the EDT. For example like so

```
public static String getFrameResult() throws InterruptedException {
    if (SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread()) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Can't be called from EDT.");
    }
    ArrayBlockingQueue<String> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(1);
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Hello");
        JButton button = new JButton("Done");
        button.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
            String result = "Done at : " + LocalDateTime.now();
            queue.offer(result);
            frame.dispose();
        });
        frame.add(button);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    });
    return queue.take();
}
```

The trick here is to store the result in memory and to notify the calling thread that it has been saved so it can take it and return it. A `BlockingQueue` works well, since Java 8 a [`CompletableFuture`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) or even manually via wait/notify and a shared variable.

Comment: So then simply write the GUI-definition inside this SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> { }); statement and the function-thread only goes on after the statement queue.offer(something); is fired?

Comment: @Jeve Yes, `take()` waits until there is something to take. Regarding `invokeLater`: gui creation should always happen within the EDT, that's not specific to this problem, but here we can guarantee that we're in the wrong thread. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html (it may work without, but it's not a good idea to do so, also `() -> { }` is equivalent to a `Runnable`, just shorter but it requires java 8)